# Ionic app - login page - text boxes do not open keyboard until other user action

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

My ionic app has a login screen when the user installs the app. By default it shows two text boxes : `user email` and `password` with a `login` button below.
On Android, if the user's first action is to tap on either text box, the keyboard does not open. However, once the button is tapped and the user taps into the text box again, the keyboard comes up. This is not the case for iOS or the browser. Any idea why the text box is disabled initially?
Why do I get this UX? Page code is below.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row header align-items-start align-items-stretch>
      <ion-col col-10 offset-1 col-md-6 offset-md-3>

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-col col-10 offset-1 col-md-6 offset-md-3>
      <form padding>
        <ion-row align-items-start>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <h1><strong>MyApp</strong></h1>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <div input-field>
              <ion-item no-padding>
                <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item no-padding>
                  <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
            <ion-row>&nbsp;
            </ion-row>
            <ion-col col-12 no-padding>
              <ion-buttons>
                <button no-margin ion-button full text-uppercase (click)="loginClick()" *ngIf="!doSignUp && !resetPWD">Login</button>
                <button no-margin ion-button full text-uppercase (click)="resetClick()" *ngIf="resetPWD">Reset</button>
                <button no-margin ion-button full text-uppercase (click)="signupClick()" color="secondary">Signup</button>
              </ion-buttons>
            </ion-col>
            <div description text-center>
              <ion-row>&nbsp;
              </ion-row>
              <ion-row>
                <!-- Reset your password button -->
                <ion-col col-12 no-padding no-margin>
                    <button no-margin ion-button clear (click)="startDemo()" color="light">Demo</button>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-12 no-padding no-margin>
                    <button no-margin ion-button clear (click)="resetPassword()" color="danger" *ngIf="!resetPWD">Reset password</button>
                    <button no-margin ion-button clear (click)="stateToLogin()" color="primary" *ngIf="resetPWD">Login</button>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </form>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```